# Git: files overwritten by checkout

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I want to checkout a branch and I got this message

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:  
    src/main/webapp/data/GuerrillaLabels.json
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

But I want those files to be overwritten

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout--f

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please first search your self in older questions and answer than post your question.

Comment: Hi Carles, there are a number of other questions related to this topic, each with answers that should be able to help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### git checkout

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---force

You can pass the `-f` (force) flag to forcefully checkout the branch, this will wipe out any changes you've made that haven't been committed.

```
git checkout -f branch
```

If you don't want to lose all your changes, you can checkout the file specifically with:

```
git checkout -- src/main/webapp/data/GuerrillaLabels.json
```

### git stash

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

You could also stash the changes that you've made and reapply them later on with

```
git stash
```

You can view your stashes with

```
git stash list
```

And you can apply those stashes by using `pop`. Passing nothing to `pop` would apply the last stashed item.

```
git stash pop
```

*Note: this approach can cause conflicts with code*.